# Problem with querySelector() not modifying value, onblur or onfocus in <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I must be screwing something up. When I try to use `querySelector()` in Javascript I can't seem to modify the value, `onblur` and `onfocus` clauses of an input tag but I can modify it's id and name using JavaScript.  Help!

I cloned a chunk of HTML code with the following;

```
const newAdjustment = lastAdjustment.cloneNode(true);
```

The input tag I'm modifying looks like this;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right entered-amount" 
  id="Amount15" name="Amount15" value="$3.00" 
  onfocus="deformatAmount(15)" onblur="recalc(15)">
</input>
```

I have no problem using `querySelector()` to modify the id and name of the input tag;

```
const originalSequenceNumber = 15;
const newSequenceNumber = originalSequenceNumber + 1;
const originalAIdName = 'Amount' + originalSequenceNumber;
const newAIdName = 'Amount' + newSequenceNumber;
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + originalAIdName).id = newAIdName;
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).name = newAIdName;
```

This leaves me with the following;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right entered-amount" 
  id="Amount16" name="Amount16" value="$3.00" 
  onfocus="deformatAmount(15)" onblur="recalc(15)">
</input>
```

I then try to modify value, `onblur` and `onfocus` with the following;

```
const newAOnfocus = 'deformatAmount(' + newSequenceNumber + ')';
const newAOnblur = 'recalc(' + newSequenceNumber + ')';
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + originalAIdName).value = "$0.00 ";
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).onfocus = newAOnfocus;
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).onblur = newAOnblur;
```

and nothing happened.  `newAOnFocus`, `newOnBlur` and the input element are as follows;

```
newAOnfocus       =  deformatAmount(16)
newAOnblur        =  recalc(16)
newAdjustment     =  <input type="text" class="form-control text-right entered-amount" id="Amount16" name="Amount16" value="$3.00" onfocus="deformatAmount(15)" onblur="recalc(15)">
```

After I append the child to the document and use `document.querySelector()` I can modify the value but not the `onblur` or `onfocus` clauses.  What am I doing wrong?  What clause am I missing from `querySelector()`?  By the way, there a three input and three button tags in `newAdjustment` and I'm having the same problem with all six.

***Correction about .value***
.value was updated correctly.  The page reflected the correct value in .value but when I did a `console.log()` of `newAdjustment` it displayed the original value from the cloning (`.cloneNode()`).  I'm wondering if I'm having the same problem with the rest, which means I'm actually not having a problem at all.  More testing to follow.

Comment: Your `newAOnfocus` and `newAOnblur` are strings and **not** `Function` objects. Try something like this `newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).onfocus = function(){deformatAmount(newSequenceNumber);};`

Comment: Alex, I could not get `function(){deformatAmount(newSequenceNumber);};` to work.  I guess I must have typed something wrong.  I ended up using Matt Clarson's solution listed below.  Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setAttribute` on the input.

So

```
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + originalAIdName).value = "$0.00 ";
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).onfocus = newAOnfocus;
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).onblur = newAOnblur;
```

Becomes

```
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + originalAIdName).setAttribute("value", "$0.00 ");
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).setAttribute("onfocus", newAOnfocus);
newAdjustment.querySelector("#" + newAIdName).setAtribute("onblur", newAOnblur);
```